# How can I get the params from the url with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to setup verify account with react and have the following in my `App.js` file

> App.js

```
import SigninPage from './pages/signin';
import ResetPasswordPage from './pages/resetPassword'
import VerifyAccountPage from './pages/verifyAccount'
...
...
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import { logout } from './utils/auth';

function App() {

  const history = useHistory();
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
        <Route
            path="/signout"
            render={() => {
              logout();
              history.push('/');
              return null;
            }}
        />
        <Route path='/signin' component={SigninPage} exact />
        <Route path='/reset-password?reset-password-token=:resetPasswordToken' component={ResetPasswordPage} />
        <Route path='/verify-account?token=:token&email=:email' component={VerifyAccountPage} exact />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and in my VerifyAccountPage component have the following

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import { verifyAccount, isAuthenticated } from '../../utils/auth';


const VerifyAccount = () => {

  const { token, email } = this.props.match.params
  const history = useHistory();
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError('');
    try {
      const data = await verifyAccount(token, email);

      if (data) {
        history.push('/');
      }
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        // handle errors thrown from frontend
        setError(err.message);
      } else {
        // handle errors thrown from backend
        setError(err);
      }
    }
  };

  return isAuthenticated() ? (
    <Redirect to="/#" />
    ) : (  
    <>
      <Container>
        <FormWrap>
          <Icon to='/'>mywebsite</Icon>
          <FormContent>
            <Form action='#'>
              <FormH1>Verify Account</FormH1>
              <Text>Account has been verified!</Text>
            </Form>
          </FormContent>
        </FormWrap>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default VerifyAccount;
```

and here is `verifyAccount.js` page

```
import React from 'react';
import VerifyAccount from '../components/VerifyAccount';
import ScrollToTop from '../components/ScrollToTop';

function VerifyAccountPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <VerifyAccount />
    </>
  );
}

export default VerifyAccountPage;
```

here is

> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but this is not working and when I go to the link `https://mywebsite.com/verify-account?token=3heubek&email=user1@email.com` nothing happens other than a 200 or 304 status code

no request is sent to the API so means that the params are not getting pulled out

can anyone point me to what is going on?

package versions used from package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^15.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question title to match the actual problem at hand? It's far too vague and open-ended as is. The core of your issue is with not being able to contact your API or not being able to read URL search parameters.

Comment: it is not being able to access the search params...did you read question at all? read question first before asking to change it

Comment: I read it... I said it's about one thing or the other - API access or query parameter reading. Your title, "how do i setup verify account with react?" is a bad title because _React_ doesn't verify accounts at all and the title doesn't actually reference the relevant library or the specific problem you're having

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `withRouter` for getting router information such as location, history, path, and params.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

...

const VerifyAccount = withRouter(props) => {
  const { token, email } = props.match.params;
  console.log("toke, email: ", token, email)     // And also show me how it looks!!!
  ...
}
```

And you should define your route like this.

```
<Route path='/verify-account/:token/:email' component={VerifyAccountPage} />
```

And you should call like this:

```
https://your-domain/verify-account/[token]/[email]
```

This will work.

Comment: Can you print the props with `console.log` and show me the result, please?

Comment: like this? ```const VerifyAccount = (props) => {

  const { token, email } = props.match.params

  console.log({'token': token, 'email': email});```

Comment: i have that and **nothing is getting logged to console** even..so am not even sure what is going on..i only get 200 or 304 status code with no other logs

Comment: I update my answer, can you show me the console log result?

Comment: And please show me the location. I've updated my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233949/discussion-between-oscar-cardoso-garcia-and-uberrebu).

Answer (score 14):

Route match params are not the same thing as URL query string parameters.

You'll want to access the query string from the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) object.

> ```
> {
>   key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
>   pathname: '/somewhere',
>   search: '?some=search-string', <-- query string
>   hash: '#howdy',
>   state: {
>     [userDefined]: true
>   }
> }
> ```

[React-router-dom query parameters demo](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

They create a custom `useQuery` hook:

```
const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
```

For your use case, on the page rendering the `VerifyAccountPage` you want to then extract the query string parameters. Given `path='/verify-account?token=:token&email=:email'`:

```
const query = useQuery();

const email = query.get('email');
const token = query.get('token');
```

### Class-based component ?

If `VerifyAccountPage` is a class-based component then you will need to access `props.location` and process the query string yourself in a lifecycle method. This is because React hooks are only validly used by functional components.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { location } = this.props;
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  
  const email = query.get('email');
  const token = query.get('token');
  ...
}
```

##### Note regarding path

```
path='/verify-account?token=:token&email=:email'
```

The path params are only relevant in the path portion of a URL, you can't define params for the queryString portion of the URL. The above path is equivalent to `path='/verify-account'` from `react-router-dom`'s perspective.

Comment: so i should have it like this?
```const VerifyAccount = () => {
  const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  const { token, email } = useQuery();

  console.log({'token': token, 'email': email});
``` is this right?

Comment: @uberrebu `useQuery` should be defined outside the component, but yes.

Comment: what do you mean outside the component? `VerifyAccountPage` is a class-based component so you mind posting how everything should look like? i imported intop the App.js file like `import VerifyAccountPage from './pages/verifyAccount'
...` i update the question to include this piece

Comment: @uberrebu Please see the last section of my answer regarding class-based components. React hooks are incompatible with class-based components, so a `useQuery` hook won't work.

Comment: so what will be the solution to go with?

Comment: @uberrebu It seems you've a functional component, so I'd go with the first. If this isn't working then perhaps you've an issue with how you are rendering routes or linking to this path/page.

Comment: yeah i posted most of all i have...page linking looks correct but maybe if you see anything off...first answer...am not even getting anything in console log

Comment: the usequery params from the codesandbox worked..thanks also

Answer (score 2):

**React JS**

```html
http://localhost:3000/#/product?id=159
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myParam = useLocation().search;
  const productId= new URLSearchParams(search).get("id");
  console.log(productId); // 159
}
```

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
const siteUrl = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(siteUrl);
console.log( urlParams['id'] ) // 159
```